Openwrt Adblock Statistics
I am trying to log blocked Requests by Adblock/openwrt
I am using this package:
1.https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/master/net/adblock/files/README.md
Hey, I am trying to log total "blocked" requests in a json file like
this :
   {
  "TOTAL": 39100,
  "BLOCKED": 16172
   }

which is being extracted from "adb_reports.json".
But, when i refresh the report to generate current report json file,
start_timestamp and end_timestamp changes (dont know how and when it changes), so i cant compute actual
total numbers.
my code is attached below.
#!/bin/bash

# Path to the JSON file
JSON_S_FILE="adb_report.json"
# Path to extracted datd file
JSON_O_FILE="stored_data.json"

# Check if the JSON file exists
if [ ! -f "$JSON_S_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Error: JSON file '$JSON_S_FILE' not found!"
    exit 1
fi

# Extract specific values using jq
TOTAL=$(jq -r '.total' "$JSON_S_FILE")
BLOCKED=$(jq -r '.blocked' "$JSON_S_FILE")

#updating values in extracted data file

if [ -s $JSON_O_FILE ] && jq empty $JSON_O_FILE >/dev/null 2>&1; then
#if exists & valid
    echo "The JSON file is valid and not empty."
    jq --arg total "$TOTAL" --arg blocked "$BLOCKED" \
       '{"TOTAL": ((.TOTAL|tonumber) + ($total|tonumber)), 
         "BLOCKED": ((.BLOCKED|tonumber) + ($blocked|tonumber))}' \
       "$JSON_O_FILE" > temp.json && mv temp.json "$JSON_O_FILE"
else
#if not, create & write!!
    echo "The JSON file is either empty or not valid."
    echo "{\"TOTAL\": \"$TOTAL\", \"BLOCKED\": \"$BLOCKED\"}" >stored_data.json
fi


Problem is that this package doesn't generate adb_report.json on its own, when I generate that json file the time stamps changes, don't know when and how,
sample Json is like below:
  "start_date": "2024-12-24",
        "start_time": "22:13:12",
        "end_date": "2024-12-25",
        "end_time": "01:05:04",
        "total": "6076",
        "blocked": "4355",
        "percent": "71.68%",

anyone know how the starting and ending time stamps change; or is there any better way to log total block requests??
thank you!

when i refresh the report to generate current report json file, start_timestamp and end_timestamp changes . So you have a data processing problem where you don't understand an issue with how your data is created. I would do something like make_report_data > /tmp/report_data.$(date %Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S), run this 3-4 times waiting a 10, 20, 40, 60 , 90, 120 seconds in between. Then grep -e start_time -e end_time /tmp/report_data.* and look to see how the start (and end) times match up with the timestamps of the files created. (you need to use the simpilest version of make_report_data) .

If that doesn't help you focus on where the problem is, then update your question with the output of the grep command so readers will have an actual set of data to ponder. Good luck.
